# Solutions to Linear Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have these two equations: $cx+y=5, x+y=2$. For what $c$ would this have no solution, infinite solution, unique solution.

For no solution I got when c=1, and for c=0, we have unique solution. Is this right, how do I find where it has infinite solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we subtract the first and the second equation, we note that
$$(c-1)x=3$$
This means that, for $c=1$ it hasn't solution ($0=3$) and for $c\neq1$ it has only one solution. Here, there isn't case of infinite solution because with the subtraction of the two equations we have not obtained $0=0$.

Comment: So for inifinitely many solutions, I can just write the empty set?

Comment: Yes, @hardwork!

Answer (score 0):

Use that if $\frac{a_1}{a_2}\neq \frac{b_1}{b_2}$, the equations will have a  unique solution, where $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ are the coefficients. So for $\frac{c}{1}\neq\frac{1}{1}$ the equations will have a unique solution. 
If $\frac{a_1}{a_2}=\frac{b_1}{b_2}\neq\frac{c_1}{c_2}$, the equations will be inconsistent. So $\frac c1=\frac11\neq\frac52$. So for $c=1$, equations will be parallel. 
For $\frac{a_1}{a_2}=\frac{b_1}{b_2}=\frac{c_1}{c_2}$, the equations will have infinite solutions. But as we see $c=1=\frac52$ is not true. So for no real value of $c$, this condition is satisfied.

Comment: So there is no c for which there are infinite solutions?

Comment: Yes, because when two lines are coincident, we can divide an equation by something to achieve the second one, that is why they are coincident! Like, $2x+2y=2$ can be divided by $2$ to be shown that it is parallel with $x+y=1$. So if we take a look at your equations, in both of them coefficient of $y$ is same but the constant terms are different. So intuitively, one can see that you cannot multiply any equation with anything to achieve the other one. So there is no real value of $c$ for that.